# How to attach to Excel process in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, excel, intellij-idea

Im trying to do this, but when I do Run->Attach to Local process, it says that no processes to attach to. Could you please help me to resolve this issue? 
I have an xll add-in and I want by running the functions in excel from it step into the relevant function in Java under IntelliJ in debug mode.

Comment: Then you need to set it up so the JVM started inside the Excel process opens up the debug port, i.e. you need to specify VM arguments for that JVM instance.